# javascript assignment and values [and coma operator]

Tags: javascript

I was following someone on twitter and he posted the following quiz:

```
var a=42,b,c;

b=a++, a++;

c=(a++,a++);

console.log(a,b,c);
```

I tested it using jsbin.com and the result is:
46
42
45

here is the test page:[sample on jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/jevuzohudajo/1/edit).

Now i will explain what I know and ask about what I don't know:

line one: `var a=42,b,c;`
this is easy declaration of three variables with assignment to the first one.

line 2 : `b=a++, a++;`
this is also easy b will be equal to a+1

but my **question #1 is: 
if we want to start a new statement; shouldn't we close the first one by a semicolon??
I mean that line two is easy if it was like this:
b=a++;
a++;
but how could we write it with a coma between them?? [ this is new to me and i feel it is newbee question ]**

line 3:`c=(a++,a++);`
now this line is the one that i couldn't figure it out. it shows an assignment but putting the brackets and separating the variable inside by coma and that would result in 45??
that is my 2nd question:

**what is the explanation of line 3??**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) : the comma operator simply evaluates all the expression and return the last one...

For the line `b=a++, a++;`, there is 2 expressions : `b=a++` and `a++`. Thus it means that the first put the value of `a` into `b` and increments `a` as the second one only increments `a`. As nothing wants the returning value of the whole expression, it acts as :

```
b = a++; // b = 42, a = 43
a++;     // a = 44
```

But for the 3rd line, c gets the result of this operation and then get the result of the 2 more incrementations of `a` and this is like :

```
a++;     // a = 45
c = a++; // c = 45, a = 46
```

Comment: sorry i wrote a coment then deleted it bec i didn't get it at first , but now it is clear.. your answer is the acceptable one